# how to set default zoom level in android google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to set default zoom level in google map to 11 miles 
can any one guide me how to achieve this?

any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this:

```
MaView mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.my_map);
MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(14);    // this isn't 11 miles.
```

Or maybe you have a `MapActivity`?  In that case, the idea is the same, but you'll get the `MapView` differently.

Answer (score 0):

`newLatLngZoom()` is the method to set zooming level. `14f` is the zoom level.

```
   mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker, 14F))
```