# Android Default Map App Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have one issue with Default Google Map app in our phone.

I m calling default map application on button click using following code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+ Global.curLatitude+","+Global.curLongitude);
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(in);
```

issue is that when map is opened, it looks with maximum zoom level, so i am able to see location with maximum zoom level. can i set zoom level with this code?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2354143/1160207

Comment: Yes, Buddy but in this link that person is using MapView within xml. Here i m calling default google Map application that already we got in our phone. so can we set zoom level with this default map app? .. i want to know about that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+ Global.curLatitude+","+Global.curLongitude+"?z=zoom");
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(in);
```

use the above code to do your requirement. and replace zoom with your desired zoom value.

Comment: Hie, thanks dude, I wanna do perfectly that u r saying.. thanks a lot..Its working fine.